# How to pop out double alert message

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. I made my first pop out confirmation alert dialog (Figure 1) but I want to pop another alert dialog window after. [image]

What I am trying to achieve, it's the following: after I click **Yes** (Figure 2) the app would lead me to my homescreen and pop out another alert dialog.

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Could you please provide your code as a code block (text) and not as an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method for the second Alert to show up, and call it when you click "YES" on the first one.

```
void showSecond(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text("Thank you for paying with us"),
        content: Icon(Icons.check_circle_outline),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: const Text('Okay'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
}
```

and your `onPressed()` of "YES" in the first alert should look something like:

```
 onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SuccessPay()));
          showSecond(context);
        },
```

It was a bit hard to replicate your code from an image, so if something it's not accurate let me now. For the next time, post your code in a `code block` instead of a picture :)

Comment: i try ur code but there is an error which is 1 positional argument expected but 0 found on my showsecond();

Comment: Ok, it may be the context missing. I made an edit to the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .then() method. Call it if the user pressed the "YES" button.
Add value when poping your dialog like this Navigator.of(dialogCtx).pop(true);

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (dialogCtx) => AlertDialog(
      // title: 
      // content: 
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(dialogCtx).pop(false);
          },
          child: const Text('CANCEL'),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(dialogCtx).pop(true);
          },
          child: const Text('YES'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ).then(
    (value) => {
      if (value == true)
        {
          // display the next dialog with the scaffolds context
        },
    },
  );
```

Comment: can i make one of the textbutton(yes) have a black color?

Comment: sure, You can use an elevated button line this...

ElevatedButton(
          style:
              ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(dialogCtx).pop(true);
          },
          child: const Text('YES'),
        ),

Answer (score 0):

you can call showAlertDialog to show second popup.(you can create new method to show second popup as content is different)This line can be added after
Navigator.of(context).pop() of first popup

Comment: can u show me some sample sir ;(